# Computing the Chern connection of a Nakano-positive curvature form

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $(E, h) \to X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle with a Hermitian metric $h$ over a complex manifold $X$. We write $D$ for the Chern connection of $h$, and $\Theta = D^2$ for its curvature form.

I'm playing around with the $(1,1)$-form that the curvature form defines on $E \otimes T_X$. It's defined by
$$
B(s \otimes \xi, t \otimes \eta) = h(\Theta_{\xi \overline\eta}s, t)
$$
for holomorphic sections $s, t$ of $E$ and holomorphic tangent fields $\xi, \eta$ on $X$, and extended by linearity to the whole of $E \otimes T_X$.

If we assume that $B$ is positive-definite, which happens when $(E,h)$ is Nakano positive, then it is again a Hermitian metric on $E \otimes T_X$ and thus has a Chern connection and curvature. I'd like to compute them.

It's enough to compute the Chern connection on holomorphic sections. If we try, we find that for the $(1,0)$-part $D'$ of the Chern connection we have
$$
B(D'(s \otimes \xi), t \otimes \eta)
= \partial B(s \otimes \xi, t \otimes \eta)
= \partial h(\Theta_{\xi \overline\eta}s, t)
= h(D'\Theta_{\xi \overline\eta}s, t).
$$
Here we've abused notation by using $D'$ for the $(1,0)$-part of two different Chern connections, but hopefully it's clear from context what is what. So far, this is all good.

I'd now *really* like to commute the $D'$ and the $\Theta$, but whenever I try I get nonsense. For example, we can note that $h(\Theta s, t) = h(s, \Theta t)$. We also note that $\Theta = \bar\partial D' + D'\bar\partial$, so $\bar\partial\Theta = \Theta\bar\partial$. In particular, if $t$ is holomorphic, then so is $\Theta t$. Using this we can try to compute
$$
\partial h(\Theta s, t)
= \partial h(s, \Theta t)
= h(D's, \Theta t) + h(s, \bar\partial \Theta t)
= h(D's, \Theta t)
= h(\Theta D's, t).
$$
This would imply that $D'(s \otimes \xi) = (D' s) \otimes \xi$. But the right-hand side here isn't well-defined on $E \otimes T_X$: The definition of the tensor product says that if $f$ is a smooth function then all of $f(s \otimes \xi)$, $(f s) \otimes \xi$ and $s \otimes (f \xi)$ are equal. Computing the LHS on any of them gives $df \otimes D(s \otimes \xi) + f D(s \otimes \xi)$, while computing the RHS on $s \otimes (f \xi)$ gives only $f D(s \otimes \xi)$.

I can't see where this goes wrong, but it clearly does. It feels like this should work, as we're just using $D D^2 = D^3 = D^2 D$ in various forms. What am I missing?